# React.js component never refreshed after fetch

Tags: fetch-api, react-starter-kit

Visual Studio React.js starter kit

I don't know why the display component isn't refreshed after fetch is handled?
the 'setResults' function is called correctly, and the data is set, but the gallery component never gets the updated data. How do I achieve this? Are the components just set up wrong to start with?

The googleapis book api is searched with 'harry potter' for example.
I get back 10 results.
But the gallery is never updated with the found data.
What do I need to trigger to make the 'gallery' display the newly found data?

I'm guessing that because the fetch.then.then async is in the background, the gallery component isn't somehow notified? I'm in the dark on react and async calls.

main component:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var BookGallery = require('./BookGallery.jsx');

var BookSearch = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      query: '',
      books: []
    };
  },
  setResults(value) {
    this.books = value.items;
    if (this.books) {
      console.log('count of books found: ' + this.books.length);
    } else {
      console.log('nothing found!');
    }
  },
  search() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=';

    if (this.query) {
      console.log("Do the search with " + this.query);

      fetch(BASE_URL + this.query, { method: 'GET' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.setResults(json));


    } else {
      console.log("Nothing to search for...");

    }
  },

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="Global">
        <h3>Book Search</h3>
        <p>
          <input
              type="search"
              id="inputBookTitle"
              onChange={event => this.query = event.target.value}
              onKeyUp={event => {
                if (event.key == "Enter") {
                  this.search();
                }
              }}
            />
          <span style={{ border: '1px solid garkgrey', padding : '5px', background: 'lightgray' }} >
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search" onClick={() => this.search()} ></span>
          </span>
        </p> 
        <BookGallery list={this.books}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = BookSearch;
```

then the gallery component:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

var BookGallery = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      books: []
    };
  },
  rate() {

    console.log("Rate the book");
  },
  render() {
    this.books = this.props.list || [];
    console.log(this.books);
    return (
      <div id="bookContainer" >
        <h4>Results:</h4>
        <ul id="gallery">
          {
            this.books.map((item, index) =>
              <li key={index}>{book}</li>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = BookGallery;
```

Comment: You should use setState function, instead of just setting the object field. Then React will know something changed..

Comment: setState is not setting books to the items.value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.books = value.items;
```

should be

```
this.setState({books: value.items});
```

React decides when to render the state based upon `setState` calls, not from just changing the state.

Also, you seem to be assuming that the state lives on `this`, it doesn't, it lives on `this.state`, so wherever you are referring to `this.books` for rendering, you should be referring to `this.state.books`.

Comment: When it runs, this call does nothing. The value.items has the data, and after the call, books is still null. The update of the view does occur, but no data is passed to the books member

Comment: setState() updates the state asynchronously, probably that's why.. You also need to update `<BookGallery list={this.books}/>` to `<BookGallery list={this.state.books}/>`,